# Entity Framework Core AddOrUpdate item optimal way

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want to update a `Developer` entity if such record with specified `DeveloperName` exists in DB, otherwise I need to add a new item. For now I do it like in the code below, but this is 2-queries way. Is there a better way?

```
   public static async Task AddOrUpdateDevAsync(Developer newD)
        {
            using (var db = new RPDBContext())
            {
                var oldD =
                    await
                        db.Developer.AsNoTracking()
                            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(
                                x =>
                                    string.Equals(x.DeveloperName, newD.DeveloperName,
                                        StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
                if (oldD != null)
                {
                    Mapper.Map(newD, oldD);
                    db.Developer.Update(oldD);
                }
                else
                {
                    db.Developer.Add(newD);
                }
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think your bigger problem are not the 2 queries, but the first query reading the whole table in memory and applying the filter there because of the used `string.Equals` overload.

Comment: is that b'cos of `string.Equals` or due to use it inside the `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` ? @IvanStoev Can you explain it little bit more ?

Comment: Such methods cannot be translated to SQL. In EF6 you'll simply get NotSupported runtime exception. In EF Core by default you get it "implemented" in memory. It's configurable, also you can turn EF Core logging and see exactly what's going on. Other that that, I don't see how 2 queries can be avoided.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev, your first comment is extra useful for me. Thank you!

Comment: @Ivan Stoev, how can I configure EFC to throw exception in this case?

Comment: Inside `OnConfiguring`, add `optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning));`

Comment: Can't avoid unwelcome comment "Thank you so much!" =)

Comment: @IvanStoev can't you put those `comments as an answer` ? Then it will help others in the future.

Comment: @Sampath Thank you for the suggestion, I could, but don't feel I should. Although it looks like my comments did somehow help OP, the issue I was commenting is not directly related to the AddOrUpdate, but EF Core queries in general.